# GCM push notification , notification click event

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I send notification according to api . I passed click_action and config in manifest. But I don't know where I can get the click event .I'm a newer on android development. What I want is to get the click callback when I click the notification . So what should I do next? I searched some answers on the website but none of them tells some details .Hope some can help me. Gratitude

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an intent filter in your AndroidManifest.xml for the activity you wish to open when the notification is clicked.

For example:

```
    <activity android:name=".SomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="SOME_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Clicking the notification will open that activity if the message payload contains (within the "notification" dictionary) the following:

```
"click_action":"SOME_ACTION"
```

If you want to run some logic when the notification is clicked, you should put that logic in `onCreate()` method of the activity that will be opened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and actually I did what you said , added an intent filter in my manifest.xml and passed click_action. But I don't know what kind of code I should write in my onCreate method.I don't know android code , and I was asked to finish this function , so what I should do is to finish it first. So can you help provide an example code like what I should write in my onCreate method? Thank you so much

Comment: @wuzinong That depends on what your app is supposed to do when the activity is opened as a result of clicking the notification. For example, it might read some custom data passed in the "data" dictionary of the message and do something with it.

Comment: Yes I put my message in data ,like{data:{message:"a",title:"b"},notification:{click_action:"SOME_ACTION"}}  and call the api to pass the data. And on android side ,I can get this data ,but I don't know how to catch the click function in my android code

Comment: @wuzinong What do you mean by "catch the click function"? Do you mean obtaining the value "SOME_ACTION"? Why do you need it? It was already used by Android to open the required Activity.

Comment: Ok , I just a little bit confused about that. I registered SOME_ACTION and there must be somewhere I should write the SOME_ACTION function .I don't know where to write and what I should write .Maybe I should learn android development from the beginning but just because this function is urgent and have no time to learn it at present.

Comment: @wuzinong Each activity of your class would have an activity class (a sub-class of `android.app.Activity`). When the activity is started, its `onCreate` method is called. You can override this method in order to write code that would be executed when the activity is started.

Comment: Yes I find my onCreate method and what kind of code that I can write in this function will be called when notification is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

There is no *callback* per se for handling notification click events on Android. Instead what is used is a [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) included when creating the notification.

To achieve what I think you're trying to achieve, which is to take different actions as suggested in the `click_action` parameter in the notification body, you may need to handle this in the `onMessageReceived` method of your class which extends `FirebaseMessagingService` (as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)).

You can have this block of code to handle the remote message:

```
private void sendMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
   if (remoteMessage.getData() > 0) {
       String action = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");

       // if you sent the notification with a "notification body", you can do this
       String notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

       // create notification with the action and the notification body
       createNotification(action, notificationBody);
   }
}

private void createNotification(String action, String notificationBody){
   // create the intent and set the action 
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeActivity.class);
   intent.setAction(action);

   // create a pending intent
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   // build the notification
   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
           .setContentTitle("My notification")
           .setContentText(notificationBody)
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent); //set the content intent

   NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   // notificationId allows you to update the notification later on.
   mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

You can then go on to retrieve the specific action within `SomeActivity` by using the `getIntent().getAction()` and handle each case of the actions.

Summarily, you really can't find a "click listener" for a notification in Android.

You can check these links: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive to further understand the process.

Cheers.

Comment: I used micrisoft azure notification hub's api to send the message website:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started   And I see there's onReceive method in NotificationsHandler  which will be called when receive notification. I wonder whether it has function like onNotificationClick , thus I can handle notification click function

Comment: And I extends com.microsoft.windowsazure.notifications.NotificationsHandler  this class ,and I can't  find sendMessage or createNotification these functions in this parent class . also for PendingIntent can't get reference . As we want to use microsoft azure notification hub to manage all the platform's push notification. Is there any other method I can use?